# iPad won't turn on after a complete battery drain

Tags: ios, ipad, battery

My iPad mini retina is out of warranty,

I forgot to plug in my iPad after the critical battery warning and it went some minutes following the warning. I was not worried because same thing had happened a few times before and iPad was perfectly okay after charging it. However, this time I remember seeing a flash of blue screen immediately after it went black. Then, I plugged it in an waited for a while and tried starting it. Ever since, it fails to start hanging on the apple logo with white background screen.

I tried to connect to my Mac but nothing showed up in iTunes. I am worried now. Can I troubleshoot this or is it broken and needing repair?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming it is now charged…

Hold Home & Power buttons for at least 45 seconds, see if it starts up normally.

If not…

- Plug your iPad's USB cable into a computer with iTunes.
- Hold down the Home button [keep holding] and connect to your iPad.
  Keep holding the Home button until you see a screen telling you to connect to iTunes.
- iTunes should show you a popup saying that there is an iPhone or iPad that is in Recovery Mode and needs to be restored before you can use it.
- Click OK.
- Click on Restore iPhone/iPad.

If the above doesn't work, you may need to get a fully operational iPad charger and plug it into the wall. The current and voltage needed to wake an iPad with a deeply discharged battery (or one that's malfunctioning due to age) is higher than a computer can provide over USB.

- Plug into a known good iPad type adapter (higher current than iPhone charger)
- Wait 15 minutes
- Try powering on
- Wait 10 minutes
- Try a hard reset (hold home button and sleep wake button together for 15 seconds)
- Wait 5 minutes
- Try powering on

At that point, you can let it charge for another hour and try again or start with a different cable or a different charger. Eventually, you'll need to have the iPad serviced if it cannot wake from sleep due to a very low batter charge condition even when plugged into power.

Comment: thank you very much! I had to Restore my iPad. Luckily there was an iCloud backup which I did not make myself!

Comment: Great fix!! I wish I could have upvoted more that once ;)

Comment: Prize tip was to use iPad charger not laptop, that got me out of the cycle of Apple Logo - empty battery icon.