# My iPad is not turning on though charged for one hour and hard reboot

Tags: ipad

I followed the steps explained in the URL below, but still the ipad is not turning on, charged using power adapter (not using laptop) for more than couple of hours and tried hard restart connecting to power and laptop. Still it is neither turning on nor recognized by itunes. I am worried. :(

[iPad won't turn on after a complete battery drain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174833/ipad-wont-turn-on-after-a-complete-battery-drain)

Comment: The battery is probably discharged below the safe point and disconnected itself for good. This is known behaviour on protected LiPo and Li-ion batteries.

Answer (score 3):

If you followed those instructions for resetting, restoring or recharging the battery in your iPad then you are left with the last line.

> Eventually, you'll need to have the iPad serviced if it cannot wake from sleep due to a very low battery charge condition even when plugged into power.

We have a number of independent phone/tablet repair shops nearby. You may as well. Ask around for a reputable one and have them look at it. Yes you could take it to an Apple store, but if the independent store is good at their job it will likely be faster and cheaper there. But totally your call.